# Searching a string and comment next line, then add new string in Shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

Using shell script, I have to update a file. For that I have to perform below operations.
I tried using `sed` but unable to perform same.

Example - file `foo.txt`

1. Search string `if[a<1]`
2. Comment next line
3. Add new line after commenting

Example

Input

```
if[a<1] 
abc
=================
```

Output (Expected result)

```
if[a<1]
# abc
xyz
=================
```

Comment: It would be easier to assist if we had an example input file and the expected result after modifications.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '
  /if\[a<1\]/{
    n
    s/.*/# &\
xyz/
  }' < file
```